# When a string is too long it automatically gets split into different lines instead of staying on a single line

Tags: string, newline

I hope the title makes sense, if it doesn't after you see the code it will make sense (again I hope).

Here I'm declaring a string (in the actual code the string sometimes longer sometimes shorter).

```
string testingsmth = khfajkwfhklajhfklahflkjahwklfjhakljfhalkjwfbhkjalwhfdlajkwhrlkjahkjehakljehakljheakwljhekljawehlkajhjekahklejahklejhakjehakljghaegawhgkjahg";
```

The output is as follows: (it shouls be on 1 line instead of X amount of lines)
ajkhfajkwfhklajhfklahflkjahwklfjhakljfhalkjwfbhkjal
whfdlajkwhrlkjahkjehakljehakljheakwljhekljawehl
kajhjekahklejahklejhakjehakljghaegawhgkjahg

The output is currently copied to clipboard or saved in a file.

Comment: The code you're showing is a synax error.  And it doesn't output anything.  Can you provide an actual example of the problem?

Comment: *The output is as follows* → Output to what/where? Are you showing the text on a `TextBox`, a `Label`? Are you saving the text in a text file and seeing the result in notepad? It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @RezaAghaei the output (result) is either saves in a txt file or it's copied to clipboard. There's nothing else to it that makes it confusing and unclear.

Comment: When you open the txt file in notepad, when word wrap is checked, it breaks the text when the text is longer than window's width. The same when you see the text in a textbox.

Comment: Anyway, I'll vote to close the question as it's not clear what you are asking and it seems it's not a question related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing the classical mistake of mixing up how something is displayed vs how it is defined in memory.

If you got a 128 character long string and try to output it into your normal 40x80 console window, there are only two options:

- Automatically wrap the string over multiple lines. 3 40-charcters ones plus 1 8 character one
- do not display more then the first 40 characters

Whatever display you are looking at, apparently choose option a - Auto Wrap. Most editors have option to turn off/on auto line wrap for display. The debugger will propably auto wrap too, to make it readable.

Comment: it's not a console app, it's a windows forms app. if the same thing applies to winforms I'll mark your question as an answer.

Comment: No, it is not a WinFroms app. It is no app at all.

Comment: "**Whatever display** you are looking at" so thanks for pointing out that I wrote the right thing here. :) I have just no idea what you tried to do here.